# php mysql edit function error submit button show error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bug in my system...when I clicked useraccounts to display the information of the users in the system it says: Notice: Undefined index: Username in C:\xampp\htdocs\GuidanceRecord\useraccounts.php on line 75
I know the problem is quite easy but I can't see what the problem is...
My useraccounts.php is:

```
<?php

$records = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db('records', $records);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM login';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $records);

echo "<table border='1' width='100%'>";





while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='20%'><img src='image/loginimage2.jpg'></img>";
echo "</td>";
echo $row['Username'];
echo "<td width='15%'><a href='#'>Guidance<br>Administrator</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a href='edituser.php?no={$row['ID']}'><input type='button' name='edit' value='Edit' class='btn btn-success'></a>";
echo "</td>";

}

echo "<td>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I also have this edituser page named edituser.php...

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
  <head>  
    <title>UCC Guidance Record System</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/global.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/textbox.js"></script>


  </head>  
  <body> 

<?php
$records = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("records",$records);


if(!isset($_POST['savechanges']))
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE ID = $_GET[no]";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$login = mysql_fetch_array($result);

}














?>
    <div class="container">

    <br>
        <div class="navbar"> 
            <div class="navbar-inner">  
                 <div class="container">
                        <ul class="nav">    
                            <li><a href="viewrecords.php">View Records</a></li>
                            <li><a href="addrecords.php">Add Records</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="useraccounts.php">User Accounts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <span class="span6">

                        </span>
                        <ul class="nav">    
                            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                 </div>
            </div>  
        </div> 



            <div class="row">
            <span class="span12">
            <img src="image/UCC Guidance Record System2.png" width="100%" height="210px"></img>
            </span>
                    <span class="span2">
                </span>


                <span class="span8">    
                    <br><br>



    <table border="0" width="100%" height="100%">

                    <tr>
                        <td width="33%">
                        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="33%">
                        User Accounts
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="33%">
                        Username:
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                        Password:
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="33%">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $login['ID']; ?>" />
                            <input type="text" name="Username" title="Username" style="color:#888;" value="<?php echo $login['Username']; ?>" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                            <input type="Password" name="Password" title="Password" style="color:#888;" value="<?php echo $login['Password']; ?>" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td width="33%">
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%">
                        <input type="submit" name="savechanges" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes">
                        </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    </table>




                </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="container"> 
        <ul class="pager container-fluid">  
            <li class="pull-left"><a href="addrecords.php">Previous</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Next</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </div>  
    </div>
    <center><small class="muted">UCC Guidance Record System<br>
    Developed by Christian Baltazar and Jocella Barruga.<br>
    Copyright 2014.</small></center>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['savechanges']))
{
$id = $_POST['ID'];
$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];

$update = "UPDATE students ".
       "SET Username = '$Username' ".
       ", Password = '$Password' ".
       "WHERE ID = $id" ;

mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());

echo "User has been modified!";
header("Location: http://localhost/GuidanceRecord/Useraccounts.php");
exit() ;
}
?>
  </body>  
</html>
```

I also have a database named "records" a table named "login" and columns named "ID", "Username", and "Password"...
I'm a newbie in php...hope you understand...
Thanks in advance for the answer... :))

Comment: what is there at line 75

Comment: @D_Vaibhavツ this is what's in line 75 echo $row['Username'];

Comment: try var_dump($result); to check what array you get, try to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

instead of

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

and also mysql is deprecated and very vulnerable to sql injection use PDO or Mysqli instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... :)
but the problem is still there...I didn't go away... :(

Comment: are u sure its Username and not username or something else

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593061/php-mysql-updating-data-error-says-unknown-column-username-in-field-list) this my new question...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your column name in database is called 'Username'? It might be 'username', as you know PHP is character sensitive.

Try running print_r to see what are you getting from database:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you output the id in the ancor link try to replce the 'ID' with 0 it specifies the columns number you wanna display out.